# How to serialize builder class with inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I faced a serialization issue of the builder class with inheritance.
It looks like the following:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class NumberRuleConfig extends BaseRuleConfig{
    private Double min;
    private Double max;
    private Double step;
    private Map<String, Object> defaultValue;

    @Builder
    public NumberRuleConfig(Boolean enabled,
                            Boolean editable,
                            Double min,
                            Double max,
                            Double step,
                            Map<String, Object> defaultValue) {
        super(enabled, editable);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.step = step;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public NumberRuleConfig(Boolean enabled, Boolean editable) {
        super(enabled, editable);
    }
}
```

Base class:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BaseRuleConfig {
    public Boolean enabled;
    public Boolean editable;

    public BaseRuleConfig() {
    }
}
```

I see the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.example.NumberRuleConfig$NumberRuleConfigBuilder and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ImmutableCollections$MapN["ruleSetDefinitions"]->com.example.RuleDefinitions["constraints"]->java.util.ArrayList[7]->com.example.NumberRule["config"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
```

Does someone know how to avoid that issue?

Comment: You are trying to serialize an instance of builder, not the actual class. Lombok's builders are not intended to be serialized. They don't follow the bean spec, so Jackson won't be able to serialize them without a designated serializer.

Answer (score 0):

The following annotation works fine:

@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder